# Slowing down the speed of Python Requests?

Tags: python, selenium, python-requests

I have written a bot for login using python.
It works without any problem when I post on chrome using Selenium, burp suite and html form.

However, when I want to use it with the requests library, the 429 code returns.

The site has cloudflare. As a result of my research, when I post using selenium, there is no problem because it makes slow post processing.

However, when I use the requests library, the error 429 returns because it does not act as a browser and posts fast.

If I use the requests library, I need to slow down the speed, make it act like a browser, not post too fast.

Is there any solution to this?

**Note: There is no header return like Retry-After, I just need to slow down the request speed.

---

Not Working;

```
import requests
import sys

def getToken(email,password):
  try:
    headers = {
    'accept':'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9',
    'accept-encoding':'gzip, deflate, br',
    'accept-language':'tr-TR,tr;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7,ht;q=0.6,nl;q=0.5',
    'cache-control':'max-age=0',
    'content-type':'text/plain'
    }
    raw = '{"Username":"'+email+'","Password":"'+password+'","GenerateToken":true}='
    login = requests.post('https://xxxxxx/login', data=raw, headers=headers)
    print(login.status_code)

except Exception as e:
    print(e)



getToken('xxxx@xxx.com','xxxxx')
```

Working (I'm posting with Chrome.):

```
<html>
<body>
<form action="https://xxxxxx/login" method="POST" enctype="text/plain">
  <input type="hidden" name="&#123;&quot;Username&quot;&#58;&quot;xxx@xxx.com&quot;&#44;&quot;Password&quot;&#58;&quot;xxxxxx&quot;&#44;&quot;GenerateToken&quot;&#58;true&#125;" value="&#13;&#10;" />
  <input type="submit" value="Submit request" />
</form>
```

---

It works when I post the html code with Selenium.
I had to add the following settings;

```
options = Options()
options.add_argument("--headless")
options.add_argument("start-maximized")
options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)
options.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ['enable-logging'])
s = Service('chromedriver.exe')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=s, options=options)
stealth(driver,
        languages=["en-US", "en"],
        vendor="Google Inc.",
        platform="Win32",
        webgl_vendor="Intel Inc.",
        renderer="Intel Iris OpenGL Engine",
        fix_hairline=True,
)
```

Comment: Have you tried adding an arbitrary delay between loops? `import time; time.sleep(5)`

Comment: I'm not talking about any loop. It returns 429 in only 1 request operation.

Comment: I want requests to act like a browser, it should run slowly. I am sending the header correctly. It works when I save html with burp suite and post from chrome. When I submit the same form with requests I get 429.

Comment: If there's only one request, then no "delay" is present at all. Idea of "slow/fast" is not applicable. Cloudflare checks not only time when request was made, it's an extremely difficult system with lots of algorithms. It is fairly easy do determine whether request was made by browser (including selenium-driven) or by `requests`. I suppose that `post` request is accepted on that page only after loading it with `get` from the same IP and after some delay, plus maybe some cookies, plus maybe specific headers, etc.